# How to fix such ClientForm bug?

Tags: python, mechanize, clientform

from mechanize import Browser
    br = Browser()
    page = br.open('http://wow.interzet.ru/news.php?readmore=23')
    br.form = br.forms().next()
    print br.form
gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roddik\Desktop\mech.py", line 6, in <module>
    br.form = br.forms().next()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 426, in forms
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-package\mechanize-0.1.11-py2.6.egg\mechanize\_html.py", line 559, in forms
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.1.11-py2.6.egg\mechanize\_html.py", line 225, in forms
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\clientform-0.2.10-py2.6.egg\ClientForm.py", line 967, in ParseResponseEx
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\clientform-0.2.10-py2.6.egg\ClientForm.py", line 1100, in _ParseFileEx
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\clientform-0.2.10-py2.6.egg\ClientForm.py", line 870, in feed
  File "D:\py26\lib\sgmllib.py", line 104, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "D:\py26\lib\sgmllib.py", line 138, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "D:\py26\lib\sgmllib.py", line 290, in parse_starttag
    self._convert_ref, attrvalue)
  File "D:\py26\lib\sgmllib.py", line 302, in _convert_ref
    return self.convert_charref(match.group(2)) or \
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\clientform-0.2.10-py2.6.egg\ClientForm.py", line 850, in convert_charref
  File "D:\py26\lib\site-packages\clientform-0.2.10-py2.6.egg\ClientForm.py", line 244, in unescape_charref

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
```

How can I fix it?

Edit:

I've fixed it this way. Is it ok? If not, how instead?

```
import ClientForm
from mechanize import Browser

def myunescape_charref(data, encoding):
    if not str(data).isdigit(): return 0
    name, base = data, 10
    if name.startswith("x"):
        name, base= name[1:], 16
    uc = unichr(int(name, base))
    if encoding is None:
        return uc
    else:
        try:
            repl = uc.encode(encoding)
        except UnicodeError:
            repl = "&#%s;" % data
        return repl

ClientForm.unescape_charref = myunescape_charref
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by urls like this

```
http://wow.zet/forum/index.php?showtopic=1197&pid=30419&st=0&#entry30419
```

ClientForm is looking for an integer after the &#

It is ok to have the # in the url, but it should be escaped in the html
as &# means a character encoding

Comment: well, I guess I don't need fragment part of the uri at all. now how do I change mechanize to replace them in html before sending to clientform?